# Creating de-normalized collection based on existing collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In my current project the mongo-db schema has been created in a very normalized manner, e.g.

Order:

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64df9e4419dd1f30acef327a"
  },
  "order_ref_id": "EBK180-2745-9485",
  "created_on": {
    "$date": "2023-10-18T04:27:39.000Z"
  },
  "inventory_item_id": "IV-hh34653e-nh6674",
  "title": "Mr",
  "first_name": "ashish",
  "middle_name": null,
  "last_name": "shamra",
  "billing_addr_line1": "10/3 basant kunj",
  "billing_addr_line2": null,
  "billing_addr_line3": null,
  "billing_city": "Kolkata",
  "billing_state": "West Bengal",
  "billing_zip": 700086,
  "delivery_addr_line1": "10/3 basant kunj",
  "delivery_addr_line2": null,
  "delivery_addr_line3": null,
  "delivery_city": "Kolkata",
  "delivery_state": "West Bengal",
  "delivery_zip": 700086,
  "mobile": {
    "$numberLong": "9999999999"
  },
  "email": "test@gmail.com",
  "amount_total": 738,
  "qty_total": 7,
  "payment_status": "SUCCESS",
  "payment_mode": "ONLINE",
  "payment_ref_id": "0692647232",
  "pmc_cd": 1,
  "pmc_type": "01",
  "customer_type": "I",
  "ord_st": "A",
  "dstr_desc": "720296",
  "dstr_cd": "570825702",
  "dstr_st": "P",
  "dstr_contactnr": 999999999,
  "svic_id": 592375
}
```

Order_details:

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64dfa08b19dd1f30acef327c"
  },
  "order_ref_id": "EBK180-2745-9485",
  "product_name": "Head Gasket",
  "product_variant": "QT",
  "color": null,
  "price": 1050,
  "qty": 7,
  "mfg_yr": 2022,
  "st": "A"
}
```

Inventory:

```json
{
_id,
inventory_item_id,
stock_count,
…
}
```

Each of these collection contains millions of documents. I am now asked to generate an api which will give consolidated result from all these collections, based on different filter values (`created_on` from the Orders collection or `product_name` from the order_details collection). As mongoDB does not support join,
following `$lookup` is running out of memory

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          dstr_cd: {
            $ne: "99999",
          },
        },
        {
          pmc_cd: 1,
        },
        {
          ord_st: {
            $in: ["A", "C", "D"],
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "order_details",
      localField: "order_ref_id",
      foreignField: "order_ref_id",
      as: "details",
    },
  },
]
```

and I am not allowed to modify any of the existing collections, I am thinking of creating a new denormalized collection which will serve the api calls,

```
denormilized_orders{
_id,
order_ref_id,
created_on,
product_name,
inventory_item_id,
…
}
```

What is most performant approach to populate the denormalized collection from the existing collections?

I am afraid that trying to populate it via external (java) application is going to be very slow considering the amount of documents present.

**Note**: There will be a one time run to populate the data based on existing records and then there will be a nightly job that will populate denormalized tables based on the new addition to the individual collections.

Comment: This is not normal for `$lookup` to be the limit for an API response. Perhaps the `$lookup` pipeline can be improved. Can you share a sample of your query with some sample documents?

Comment: @nimrodserok, added one of the small sample documents and the aggregation query for your reference.

Comment: I am very surprised the aggregation pipeline you show is running out of memory.  ... or is your local api attempting to locally store in memory the result of that query and the local machine is running out of memory?  I.e., the MongoDB server isn't reporting an out-of-memory error, is it?

Comment: I agree with @rickhg12hs. This looks like a very simple task for mongoDB. I see no reason to experience a limitation here. How many documents matches this first `$match` step?

Comment: @nimrodserok, the order collection contains ~90 million document and order_details around 430 million documents. While trying to run the aggregation pipeline I get the error "$addToSet used too much memory and cannot spill to disk. Memory limit : 134217728"

Comment: 1. There is no `$addToSet` on the pipeline you shared with us. Is there another part of the pipeline? 2. I was asking about the match stage. How many documents passed this stage? Do you indexes to support it?

Comment: After the $match stage there are around 76 million records. The pipeline does work if I limit the result of the match stage to an extremely low count. Also, even when the pipeline does succeed the processing time is about 10 seconds. Other than indexing the join fields is there anything else I may do to improve the performance?